# Google Developers Console - Oauth consent screen configuration doesn't save the input

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to connect my application with Google calendar to receive data. I registered a new application in Google Developers Console, activated Google Calender API and tried to configure the Oauth consent screen. 
There I selected my email address, entered a product name and tried to save it.
What it says:

> Sorry, there’s a problem. If you entered information, check it and try again. Otherwise, the problem might clear up on its own, so check back later.

[image: Link]

What's my mistake here? By Google it is not the best failure description. I also can not find anything else about it in the internet, only that some one suggested to enter a billing account, what I don't want. Any ideas?

Comment: I found a solution to that, what is not really one. I created a new account and then it was possible. There might have been settings in the two profiles of mine, I have tried with, which may create some conflicts. Which problematic settings there are, I can not say.

Comment: Getting a similar error, but creating a new account is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I signed out of all Google accounts, signed back in, and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the some problem. 
I used google cloud with two accounts, i guess there is conflict with two accounts. I clean the chrome browser history and cache , then the problem is solved.

Comment: cleaning the browser history and cache on any browser wasn't the solution for me

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is here within this last week in 2020, this is a GSuite bug that's being tracked here -

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150325704

No one has been able to update or create add-ons. Clearing cache, incognito - none of it has any effect here. Just have to wait for the devs.